# Mandatory checkbox selection in a group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a group of checkboxes. By default, few of them are checked. Once the user starts unchecking and when he unchecks last but one, I want to disable the last check box so that I am mandating one selection should always be there. Also, when he checks back the last but one, disabled checkbox should be enabled.

```
   let hiddenCount = 0; let lastField;

   this.checkBoxes.find((f) => {
    if (!f.showDefault) {
      hiddenCount++;
    } else {
      lastField = f;
    }
  });

  this.checkBoxes.find((p) => {
    if (totalCount - hiddenCount === 1 && lastField) {
      p.disable = lastField.key === p.key;
    } else {
      p.disable = false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please add executable code to better debug